how to fix SMTPServerDisconnected at /accounts/register/ Connection unexpectedly closed in django
I am working on a project using django where the user needs to register and get the activation link on email and login. everything is working fine user can  register but not able to see activation link on email instead it brings the error: SMTPServerDisconnected at /accounts/register/ Connection unexpectedly closed in django
here is part of my settings.py   i have my .env file where i kept my MAIL = rukiaselemani360@gmail.com and PASSWORD  i put the password generated by App Password after two-factor authentication enabled on  Gmail account.
# settings.py

mail = os.environ.get("MAIL")
mail_pass = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = mail
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = mail_pass
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = mail

# views.py

from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, login
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    messages_to_display = messages.get_messages(request)
    return render(request, "index.html", {"messages": messages_to_display})

def register_user(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()  # Initialize the form instance
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = "Activate your Account"
            message = render_to_string("registration/account_activate_email.html", {
                "user": user,
                "domain": current_site.domain,
                "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                "token": account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()

            messages.success(request, "Please check your email to complete the registration")
            return redirect("index")
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {"form": form})

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()

    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        login(request, user)

        messages.success(request, "Your account has been successfully activated!")
        return redirect(reverse("login"))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Activation Link is Invalid or Expired")
        return redirect("index")


